# .htaccess first 3 characters as folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure if it's even possible to do this, because searching for answer didn't help (although to be honest, I'm not really sure how to even google this). Anyways, I have a domain for static files (images) media.mydomain.com . All images have random names and are just there in the home folder of the domain. Like this: media.mydomain.com/123abcdefgh.jpg . However, I would like to organize them into folders, so I wouldn't have 100.000 files in one folder. Basically, I would love to have something like this media.mydomain.com/123/abcdefgh.jpg . First 3 characters of the string is folder name, others are file name. This URL also looks fine and if there's no solution, I will go with it. However, maybe it's possible to use .htaccess and somehow make it take first 3 characters of the request uri and rewrite them into folder and the rest of the string into filename? So when you go to media.mydomain.com/123abcdefgh.jpg server will access media.mydomain.com/123/abcdefgh.jpg . I hope my question is clear. Is is possible to do this somehow? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]{3}/
RewriteRule ^(.{3})(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1/$2 [L,R=302,NC]
```